# What host should I specify in my production Knex build to deploy on heroku?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, knex.js

I have a knexfile that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {

  testing: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'poker_handsdb'
    },
    pool: {
      min:2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'poker_handsdb',
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }, 

  production: { 
    client: 'postgresql', 
    connection: {
      database: 'poker_handsdb',
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
   },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }
};
```

I deployed the app to heroku, and when I try to run knex migrate:latest, I get this error: 
 connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

What do I need to specify as the host/db to get a production build to run on heroku? Does it make sense that I am trying to run a locally-hosted postgres instance on heroku?

Comment: You need to get the url of the database from Heroku dashboard and use it in the production connection. It should be a url that starts with `postgres://`

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. I never created a database on heroku. If I run heroku pg I get "<appname> has no databases". How can I create a new postrgres db on heroku?